# How to acess a fragment function in the activity? Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with several fragments. In that activity I want to be able to access a function created in a fragment.

Fragment:

```
public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {

    public void randomfuntion (){

    }

}
```

Activity:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity{

    Fragment randomname;

    public void anotherrandomfuntion (){
        randomname. // I want to have access to randomfuntion
    }

}
```

Help?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do exactly the same thing, but I keep getting a NullPointer. Does this still work? I know it has been awhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(RandomFragment)randomname.randomfuntion()` should work